# How to condense iframe contents into one column on mobile device [HTML]

Tags: html, iframe, responsive-design, square

[image: goal desktop]

[image: goal mobile]

When adjusting screen width via Chrome, appears this iframe may indeed be capable to display in single column.

My solutions have not rendered much fluidity [or response] upon screen width, offering two columns during both mobile and desktop experience; ideal outcomes are the attached jpg and png.

A format I've explored:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iframe.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class=iframe>
   <iframe src="https://my-business-108832-108828.square.site/s/appointments"
style="
    position: ;
    max-width: ;
    height: ;
"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If css:

```
.iframe {
   position: ;
   padding-bottom: ;
   height: ;
   overflow: ;
}
```

iPad consideration could be nice, though not necessary.

Comment: unclear how the iframe would change the layout of the page. So you tryig to make the iframe take up 100% of the browser?

Comment: The contents of the page are 100% iframe; thought is to achieve a one-column display on mobile device [wo margin]